# Skyrim book (possibly in-game) about a boy trained by a Khajiit to become a sneak thief

Tags: story-identification, books, the-elder-scrolls, skyrim

I'm looking for a book, possibly from in-game, that takes place in *Skyrim*.

I don't have all the details, other than a boy trained by a Khajiit to become a sneak thief or something similar. I think the Khajiit helps the boy learn how to roll when landing from high places.

Comment: Are these books that appear in the game or a real-world novel set in the Skyrim universe?

Comment: @amaranth - Fan-fiction, apparently.

Comment: @Valorum - Actually, if the answer below is correct, it's from the In-game books in Skyrim.  Now that I see the titles, I remember them.

Comment: Indeed, they are actual books in the game.

Comment: Yup.  This belongs on http://gaming.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @can-ned_food Maybe? Hard to say, since it's technically a book identification request (even if a digital one), [which is allowed here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-book-movie-tv-series-identification-questions-allowed).

Comment: @Mwr247  Perhaps it is — but I read it as asking “looking for” i.e. ‘where can I find it?’

Comment: @Mwr247 - It's on-topic. It's just a badly worded question

Comment: In the absence of a response from the user, I'm going to take a whack at restructuring it to be a bit more useful - rollback or make your own edit, if you don't like :)

Answer (score 5):

You already got your answer on your [Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/61x06s/looking_for_a_book/dfi96m3/) asking the same thing.

The series is called [T*he Adventures of Eslaf Erol*](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Adventures_of_Eslaf_Erol), of which there are four books: *Beggar*, *Thief*, *Warrior*, and *King*.

Comment: When the question is moved over to [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), this answer should point to the locations where the specific book can be obtained.

Comment: Assuming it is moved there. Per my previous comment in response to you, the question is asking for a book identification (which is allowed here, and a digital book is still a book), and not specifically game related details (like where to find it in game).